# Is it safe to temporarily redefine \and, \or, and \not?

Tags: macros, symbols, best-practices, primitives

I'm writing lots of logic expressions in LaTeX and I'd much rather write `$p \and \not q \or r$` than `$p \land \lnot q \lor r$`. I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
\newenvironment{logic}{%
\renewcommand\and\land%
\renewcommand\or\lor%
\renewcommand\not\lnot%
}{}
```

Then I could simply

```
\begin{logic}
    p \and \not q \or r
\end{logic}
```

Are the commands `\and`, `\or`, and `\not` built into TeX? Is it safe to temporarily redefine them? If not, can you recommend any alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: Another option is to use upper case letters for your commands: `\AND`, `\OR`, and `\NOT`.

Comment: Ew! But yes, I guess that would work.

Comment: If all you're after is a faster way to write those symbols you might be better of using an editors features for this, e.g. to use snippets management or autocompletion features.

Comment: I also want to be able to read the source in the future, after not having look at it for a while.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are not built into TeX (which is called primitive in TeX). For example, `\and` is defined by `latex` as `\end {tabular}\hskip 1em \@plus .17fil\begin {tabular}[t]{c}`. However `\or`, unlike `\and` and `\not`, is not a macro but a TeX primitive. It is not a good idea to redefine it.

I think you do can overwrite them if you like as long as you enclose them within in a group, or you won't use their original meaning. For example, you are not likely to use `\and` after `\author` in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you describe what they do, or at least refer me to somewhere I could find out?

Comment: `\and` is used within in `\author`. The standard classes define `\maketitle` such that before `\@author` is typeset, a `\begin{tabular}...` is insert, and after that `\end{tabular}`, sort of. `\not` is just a macro for typeset a math char. `\or` is used in `\ifcase`, another primitive. For reference of primitives, The TeXbook is the ultimate source. http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html is also a good place to find things about that. For other `latex` or plain tex macros, there is no one-stop place to learn.

Comment: Slight problem: some documentclasses need their specific definition of `\and` in the headers. (Journal styles with authors in header, mostly.)

Answer (score 5):

The macros `\and` and `\not` are predefined in LaTeX, but the former is generally used in the `\author{}` command to separate authors, while the latter is used (generally) to form the negation of already-existing symbols, as in `\not\perp` (not orthogonal).

The MWE below uses the `\xspace` macro to automate good spacing following the redefined commands in non-math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newenvironment{logic}
   {\renewcommand{\and}{\ensuremath{\land}\xspace}
    \renewcommand{\or}{\ensuremath{\lor}\xspace}
    \renewcommand{\not}{\ensuremath{\lnot}}}
   {}     
\begin{document}
\begin{logic}
$p$ \and \not $q$ \or $r$ 
\end{logic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to restore the original meanings of the commands since they get restored automatically when you leave the group where the new meanings are defined. Of course saving them is probably the smart thing to do since you *might* want to use the original command(s) in your environment for something. PS: It should probably be `\renewcommand{\and}{\ensuremath{\land}\xspace}` - the two symbols *might* not be the same in all fonts

Comment: This is wrong under many respects: the spacing in the formula is completely fooled up; and if you happen to use `\begin{logic}...\foo...\end{logic}`, where `\foo` is based on the primitive `\or`, you'll understand why a primitive should never be redefined unless in a very controlled environment.