# Tabular error: \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }

Tags: tables, memoir

I can't understand this error message:

```
ERROR: Class memoir Error: .

--- TeX said ---

See the memoir class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.41 \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c }

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand{\and}{\wedge}
\renewcommand{\or}{\vee}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c }
$(x_1\or x_2)$ & $(\bar{x_2} \or c)$ & $(x_2\or x_3)$ & $(x_3\or x_4)$ \\
\hline
 0000 &  0100 &  0000 &  0000 \\
 0001 &  0101 &  0001 &  0100 \\
 0010 &  1100 &  1000 &  1000 \\
 0011 &  1101 &  1001 &  1100 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well for one thing, I'm not really sure you should have redefined `\and` and `\or` like this. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/is-it-safe-to-temporarily-redefine-and-or-and-not

Comment: `\vee` and  `\wedge` already have the aliases `\land` and `\lor`. ***Never*** redefine a command you don't know about.

Comment: Usually very common words are already defined. Don't redefine those either.